# How do I catch exceptions occurring during HikariPool intialization in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, hikaricp

My database has limited active connections which results in a HikariPool initialization exception as shown below for which I want to neglect the entire stack trace and catch the exception in my Main class.

Here's a stack trace of my exception log:

```
2020-11-18 16:27:16.619  INFO 9124 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-11-18 16:27:18.344 ERROR 9124 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: User 6eX6BxR3TY already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
```

Here's the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class NseapiApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NseapiApplication.class);

    private static String splunkUrl;

    @Value("${splunk.url}")
    public void setSplunkUrl(String splunkUrl) {
        NseapiApplication.splunkUrl = splunkUrl;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NseapiApplication.class, args);
        LOGGER.info("Forwarding logs to Splunk Cloud Instance : " + splunkUrl);

    }

    @Bean
    public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor dependsOnPostProcessor() {
        return bf -> {
            String[] jpa = bf.getBeanNamesForType(EntityManagerFactory.class);
            Stream.of(jpa).map(bf::getBeanDefinition).forEach(it -> it.setDependsOn("databaseStartupValidator"));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public DatabaseStartupValidator databaseStartupValidator(DataSource dataSource) {
        DatabaseStartupValidator dsv = new DatabaseStartupValidator();
        dsv.setDataSource(dataSource);
        dsv.setValidationQuery(DatabaseDriver.MYSQL.getValidationQuery());
        return dsv;
    }
}
```

Here's the Database Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatasourceConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                    .url("jdbc:mysql://myDbUrl").username("myUserName").password("myPassword")
                    .build();

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you manually creating a Datasource instead of using the Spring Boot auto-configured one? With that just limit the initial pool size to 1 instead of the default 10 and do proper connection idle checks and validation. You shouldn't use a validation query but rather rely on the JDBC 4 validation checks.

Comment: @M.Deinum : My remote database supports only 1 active connection, so If another instance of my application is accessing the same, I get this :

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: User 6eX6BxR3TY already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

The above exception generates lengthy stacktrace which I need to catch and log it as an error.